# Capture request response code of rejected promises with Promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using `Promise.allSettled` to call an array of URLs and I need to capture the response code of the request(s) of the rejected promise(s). Using the value of `result.reason` provided by `Promise.allSettled` is not accurate enough to assess the reason of rejection of the promise. I need the request response code (400, 500, 429, etc.).

I have so far the below:

```
var response = await Promise.allSettled(urls.map(url => fetch(url)))
    .then(results => {
        var data = [];
        results.forEach((result, num) => {
            var item = {
                'req_url': urls[num],
                'result': result.status,
                'result_details': result
            };
            data.push(item);
        });
        return data;
    });
```

How could I capture the response code of the request of the rejected promise and add it as a property within the returned array? The returned array should look ideally like this:

```
[{
    'req_url': 'https://myurl.xyz/a',
    'req_status_code': 400,
    'result': 'rejected',
    'result_details': {
        'status': 'rejected',
        'message': 'TypeError: Failed to fetch at <anonymous>:1:876'
    }
},
{
    'req_url': 'https://myurl.xyz/b',
    'req_status_code': 419,
    'result': 'rejected',
    'result_details': {
        'status': 'rejected',
        'message': 'TypeError: Failed to fetch at <anonymous>:1:890'
    }
},
{
    'req_url': 'https://myurl.xyz/c',
    'req_status_code': 429,
    'result': 'rejected',
    'result_details': {
        'status': 'rejected',
        'message': 'TypeError: Failed to fetch at <anonymous>:1:925'
    }
}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your current code. If the response code exists, it will be in `results`. If the server does not send that information in the response, then there's nothing you can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` doesn't reject its promise on HTTP failure, only *network* failure. (An API footgun in my view, which [I wrote up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) a few years back on my anemic old blog.) I usually address this by wrapping `fetch` in something that *does* reject on HTTP failure. You could do that as well, and make the failure status available on the rejection reason. (But you don't have to, see further below.)

```
class FetchError extends Error {
    constructor(status) {
        super(`HTTP error ${status}`);
        this.status = status;
    }
}
async function goFetch(url, init) {
    const response = await fetch(url, init);
    if (!response.ok) {
        // HTTP error
        throw new FetchError(response.status);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Then you could pass an `async` function into `map` to handle errors locally, and use `Promise.all` (just because doing it all in one place is simpler than doing it in two places with `Promise.allSettled`):

```
const results = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
    try {
        const response = await goFetch(url);
        // ...you might read the response body here via `text()` or `json()`, etc...
        return {
            req_url: url,
            result: "fulfilled",
            result_details: /*...you might use the response body here...*/,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            req_url: url,
            result: "rejected",
            result_status: error.status, // Will be `undefined` if not an HTTP error
            message: error.message,
        };
    }
}));
```

Or you can do it without a `fetch` wrapper:

```
const results = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) {
            // Local throw; if it weren't, I'd use Error or a subclass
            throw {status: response.status, message: `HTTP error ${response.status}`};
        }
        // ...you might read the response body here via `text()` or `json()`, etc...
        return {
            req_url: url,
            result: "fulfilled",
            result_details: /*...you might use the response body here...*/,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            req_url: url,
            result: "rejected",
            result_status: error.status, // Will be `undefined` if not an HTTP error
            message: error.message,
        };
    }
}));
```

Comment: Great, thank you for that tip!